# Can Google Play Feature Graphic contain download badges?

Tags: google-play, app-store

Is it a good idea for the google play feature graphic to contain download badges (Get it on google play and download on app store)?
If yes, can it contain one for both stores? (Google Play and the App Store)
Thank you.

Comment: App store here means Apple's one? Why would you need to do so?

Comment: Just to brag about the app.. and that was my question.. would it appear off-context?

Answer (score 0):

It would look very silly, as the only person seeing it would be already using Google Play on an Android device. I wouldn't do it.